# Optimize CSS Rule Dumper

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, userscript

I have written the following Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script. I am trying to obtain a list of all CSS rules for a page; across all stylesheets. As of now, I am just iterating over everything. Is there a faster way to obtain the rules? Also, I feel that there is a more efficient way of converting the CSS text to an object, but right now, all I can think to do is to tokenize the property-value pairs by spliting.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Dump CSS Rules
// @namespace    example.css.rules
// @version      0.1
// @description  Print out all the CSS rules
// @author       You
// @grant        GM_log
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    /*jslint browser: true*/ /*global  $*/
    'use strict';
    function getRules() {
        var rulesList = [];
        searchStyleSheets(rulesList);
        return rulesList;
    }
    function searchStyleSheets(rulesList) {
        var styleSheets = document.styleSheets || [];
        for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
            // CSSStyleSheet
            searchRulesList(styleSheets[i], undefined, undefined, undefined, rulesList);
        }
    }
    function searchRulesList(styleSheet, href, media, rules, rulesList) {
        // CSSRuleList
        var rules = rules || styleSheet.rules || styleSheet.cssRules || [];
        var href = href || styleSheet.href || '';
        var media = media || styleSheet.media.mediaText || '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            addRule(rules[i], href, media, rulesList);
        }
    }
    function addRule(rule, href, media, rulesList) {
        // CSSMediaRule
        if (rule.type === 4) {
            var rules = rule.rules || rule.cssRules || [];
            var href = rule.parentStyleSheet.href || '';
            var media = rule.media.mediaText || '';
            searchRulesList(rule, href, media, rules, rulesList);
        } else {
            // CSSStyleRule
            rulesList.push({
                'selector' : rule.selectorText,
                'css'      : cssTextToObject(getCssText(rule), rule),
                'href'     : href,
                //'self'   : rule,
                'media'    : media,
                'type'     : rule.type
            });
        }
    }
    function getCssText(rule) {
        return (function(text) {
            return text.substr(text.indexOf('{')) ;
        }(rule.cssText ? rule.cssText : rule.style.cssText));
    }
    function cssTextToObject(cssText, rule) {
        var m = cssText.match(/^\{(?:[ ]*)?(.*)(?:[ ]*)?\}$/);
        if (m != null) {
            var obj = {};
            if (m.length === 2) {
                var properties = m[1].split(/(?:[ ]*)?[;](?:[ ]*)?/);
                for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                    var pair = properties[i].split(/(?:[ ]*)?[:](?:[ ]*)?/);
                    if (pair.length === 2) {
                        obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        } else {
            return cssText;
        }
    }
    GM_log(JSON.stringify(getRules(), undefined, '    '));
}())
```

Here are the rules for this page:

```js
[
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_Hover_Frame",
        "css": {
            "border-radius": "0.25em",
            "box-shadow": "rgb(136, 51, 170) 0px 0px 15px",
            "-webkit-box-shadow": "rgb(136, 51, 170) 0px 0px 15px",
            "display": "inline-block",
            "position": "absolute",
            "border": "1px solid rgb(170, 102, 221) !important"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_Hover_Arrow",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "width": "15px",
            "height": "11px",
            "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_About",
        "css": {
            "position": "fixed",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "auto",
            "text-align": "center",
            "border": "3px outset",
            "padding": "1em 2em",
            "color": "black",
            "cursor": "default",
            "font-family": "message-box",
            "font-size": "120%",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "text-indent": "0px",
            "text-transform": "none",
            "line-height": "normal",
            "letter-spacing": "normal",
            "word-spacing": "normal",
            "word-wrap": "normal",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "float": "none",
            "z-index": "201",
            "border-radius": "15px",
            "box-shadow": "rgb(128, 128, 128) 0px 10px 20px",
            "-webkit-box-shadow": "rgb(128, 128, 128) 0px 10px 20px",
            "background-color": "rgb(221, 221, 221)"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_Menu",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "color": "black",
            "width": "auto",
            "padding": "2px",
            "border": "1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204)",
            "margin": "0px",
            "cursor": "default",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-size": "12px",
            "font-family": "'Segoe UI'",
            "font-variant": "normal",
            "text-align": "left",
            "text-indent": "0px",
            "text-transform": "none",
            "line-height": "normal",
            "letter-spacing": "normal",
            "word-spacing": "normal",
            "word-wrap": "normal",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "float": "none",
            "z-index": "201",
            "box-shadow": "rgb(128, 128, 128) 0px 10px 20px",
            "-webkit-box-shadow": "rgb(128, 128, 128) 0px 10px 20px",
            "background-color": "white"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuItem",
        "css": {
            "padding": "2px 2em",
            "background": "transparent"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuArrow",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "right": "0.5em",
            "color": "rgb(102, 102, 102)"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuActive .MathJax_MenuArrow",
        "css": {
            "color": "white"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuArrow.RTL",
        "css": {
            "left": "0.5em",
            "right": "auto"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuCheck",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "0.7em"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuCheck.RTL",
        "css": {
            "right": "0.7em",
            "left": "auto"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuRadioCheck",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "1em"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuRadioCheck.RTL",
        "css": {
            "right": "1em",
            "left": "auto"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuLabel",
        "css": {
            "padding": "2px 2em 4px 1.33em",
            "font-style": "italic"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuRule",
        "css": {
            "border-top-width": "1px",
            "border-top-style": "solid",
            "border-top-color": "rgb(204, 204, 204)",
            "margin": "4px 1px 0px"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuDisabled",
        "css": {
            "color": "graytext"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_MenuActive",
        "css": {
            "color": "highlighttext",
            "background-color": "highlight"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_Menu_Close",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "width": "31px",
            "height": "31px",
            "top": "-15px",
            "left": "-15px"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_Zoom",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "overflow": "auto",
            "display": "block",
            "z-index": "301",
            "padding": "0.5em",
            "border": "1px solid black",
            "margin": "0px",
            "font-weight": "normal",
            "font-style": "normal",
            "text-align": "left",
            "text-indent": "0px",
            "text-transform": "none",
            "line-height": "normal",
            "letter-spacing": "normal",
            "word-spacing": "normal",
            "word-wrap": "normal",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "float": "none",
            "box-shadow": "rgb(170, 170, 170) 5px 5px 15px",
            "-webkit-box-shadow": "rgb(170, 170, 170) 5px 5px 15px",
            "background-color": "rgb(240, 240, 240)"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_ZoomOverlay",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "0px",
            "top": "0px",
            "z-index": "300",
            "display": "inline-block",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "border": "0px",
            "padding": "0px",
            "margin": "0px",
            "opacity": "0",
            "background-color": "white"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_ZoomFrame",
        "css": {
            "position": "relative",
            "display": "inline-block",
            "height": "0px",
            "width": "0px"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_ZoomEventTrap",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "0px",
            "top": "0px",
            "z-index": "302",
            "display": "inline-block",
            "border": "0px",
            "padding": "0px",
            "margin": "0px",
            "opacity": "0",
            "background-color": "white"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_Preview",
        "css": {
            "color": "rgb(136, 136, 136)"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_Message",
        "css": {
            "position": "fixed",
            "left": "1em",
            "bottom": "1.5em",
            "border": "1px solid rgb(149, 149, 149)",
            "margin": "0px",
            "padding": "2px 8px",
            "z-index": "102",
            "color": "black",
            "font-size": "80%",
            "width": "auto",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "background-color": "rgb(230, 230, 230)"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": "#MathJax_MSIE_Frame",
        "css": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": "0px",
            "left": "0px",
            "width": "0px",
            "z-index": "101",
            "border": "0px",
            "margin": "0px",
            "padding": "0px"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "selector": ".MathJax_Error",
        "css": {
            "color": "rgb(204, 0, 0)",
            "font-style": "italic"
        },
        "href": "",
        "media": "",
        "type": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

- `// @author You`: this is a default value when you make a new userscript in Tampermonkey, but you really ought to change it.
- `getRules`: instead of having this function in here, and keeping `rulesList` as a global, consider using a constructor model instead:

```
var RuleDumper = function(){
    this.rulesList = [];
}
RuleDumper.prototype.run = function(){
    this.searchStyleSheets();
}
// ...
var RD = new RuleDumper();
RD.run();
```

- `searchStyleSheets`: you shouldn't be passing in `undefined`, and as JavaScript explicitly require all the arguments, you can just pass in `styleSheets[i]`.
- `searchRulesList`: you don't need the `var` keyword for `href`, `media` and `rules` because they're parameters and defined there.
- In your `for` loop in `searchStyleSheets`, define the length instead of checking it each time.
- In `cssTextToObject`, reverse the initial condition (`m != null`) and `return` first, that way you can remove a layer from the rest of the code.
- `rule.cssText ? rule.cssText : rule.style.cssText` can be simplified to `rule.cssText || rule.style.cssText`.
- `getCssText` is effectively useless, and should be moved into `cssTextToObject`, which would then be called `cssToObject`.
- Your comment is helpful, but you should swap this magic number (`rule.type === 4`) with a constant. E.G. `var MEDIA_RULE_TYPE = 4;` (note the case, it signifies a constant)
- Your closure looks like the following:

> ```
> (function() {
> }())
> ```

Consider adding a semicolon at the end, it's better form.

---

I have a problem with the following:

> ```
> function searchRulesList(styleSheet, href, media, rules) {
>     // CSSRuleList
>     var rules = rules || styleSheet.rules || styleSheet.cssRules || [];
>     var href = href || styleSheet.href || '';
>     var media = media || styleSheet.media.mediaText || '';
>     for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
>         addRule(rules[i], href, media);
>     }
> }
> function addRule(rule, href, media) {
>     // CSSMediaRule
>     if (rule.type === 4) {
>         var rules = rule.rules || rule.cssRules || [];
>         var href = rule.parentStyleSheet.href || '';
>         var media = rule.media.mediaText || '';
>         searchRulesList(rule, href, media, rules);
>     } else {
> ```

Other than the re-definition of `rules`, `href` and `media` in both functions, what you pass into `addRule` as `href` and `media` are completely unused.

For `href`, you pass in the style sheet's href, and then redefine it as the rule's parent stylesheet's href. Literally the same effect.

I can see basically the same thing for `media`, so don't redefine them.

---

Another huge problem I have is your constant passing of `rulesList` between functions, even though only one function uses it. Normally, you might consider a global instead, but, using the constructor model I described earlier, you can avoid both from occurring.

---

With all those changes in mind, this is what your code would look like:

```
(function() {
    /*jslint browser: true*/ /*global  $*/
    'use strict';
    var RuleDumper = function(){
        this.rulesList = [];
    };
    RuleDumper.prototype.run = function(){
        this.searchStyleSheets();
        return this.rulesList;
    };
    RuleDumper.prototype.searchStyleSheets = function(){
        var styleSheets = document.styleSheets || [];
            for (var i = 0, length = styleSheets.length; i < length; i++) {
            // CSSStyleSheet
            this.searchRulesList(styleSheets[i]);
        }
    };
    RuleDumper.prototype.searchRulesList = function(styleSheet, href, media, rules) {
        // CSSRuleList
        rules = rules || styleSheet.rules || styleSheet.cssRules || [];
        href  = href  || styleSheet.href  || '';
        media = media || styleSheet.media.mediaText || '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            this.addRule(rules[i], href, media);
        }
    };
    RuleDumper.prototype.addRule = function(rule, href, media) {
        // CSSMediaRule
        if (rule.type === 4) {
            var rules = rule.rules || rule.cssRules || [];
            this.searchRulesList(rule, href, media, rules);
        } else {
            // CSSStyleRule
            this.rulesList.push({
                'selector' : rule.selectorText,
                'css'      : this.cssToObject(rule),
                'href'     : href,
                //'self'   : rule,
                'media'    : media,
                'type'     : rule.type
            });
        }
    }
    RuleDumper.prototype.cssToObject = function(rule) {
        var cssText = (function(text){
                          return text.substr(text.indexOf('{'))
                      })(rule.cssText || rule.style.cssText);
        var m = cssText.match(/^\{(?:[ ]*)?(.*)(?:[ ]*)?\}$/);
        if (m == null) {
            return cssText;
        }
        var obj = {};
        if (m.length === 2) {
            var properties = m[1].split(/(?:[ ]*)?[;](?:[ ]*)?/);
            for (var i = 0, length = properties.length; i < length; i++) {
                var pair = properties[i].split(/(?:[ ]*)?[:](?:[ ]*)?/);
                if (pair.length === 2) {
                    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    var RD = new RuleDumper();
    GM_log(JSON.stringify(RD.run(), undefined, '    '));
}());
```

Comment: Nice improvements, but I don't think this has ever passed JSLint. The code has missing semicolons and incorrect whitespace.

Comment: @XP1 JSLint is outdated, and whitespace and semicolons are usually preferences set by the project author. [Standard JS](http://standardjs.com/rules.html) doesn't even use semicolons

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the original poster was the one who put the JSLint directive.